# Javascript code - how to make it simplier

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote sem HTML and javascript code for my project. I am new to javascript, trying to learn this language. GPT is most usefull  here... but only until you have 20-50 lines of code.

Here is my problem: Some of the statements are doubled.

After dimensions there is a part of code that shows three times.
Can I just write this part of the code once?

```
var izbranaDimenzija = izbranaSirina + "x" + izbranaVisina;
var dimenzije = Object.keys(ceneVrat);

for (var i = 0; i \< dimenzije.length; i++) {
var dimenzija = dimenzije\[i\];

if (dimenzija.includes("-")) {
var razpon = dimenzija.split("-");
var minDimenzije = razpon\[0\].split("x");
var maxDimenzije = razpon\[1\].split("x");
var minSirina = parseInt(minDimenzije\[0\]);
var maxSirina = parseInt(maxDimenzije\[0\]);
var minVisina = parseInt(minDimenzije\[1\]);
var maxVisina = parseInt(maxDimenzije\[1\]);

    if (
      izbranaSirina >= minSirina &&
      izbranaSirina <= maxSirina &&
      izbranaVisina >= minVisina &&
      izbranaVisina <= maxVisina
    ) {
      cenaVrata += ceneVrat[dimenzija];
      break;
    }

} else if (dimenzija === izbranaDimenzija) {
cenaVrata += ceneVrat\[dimenzija\];
break;
}
}

if (izbranaBarva == "RAL8014") {
cenaVrata +=  50 + izbranaSirina \* izbranaVisina / 1000000;
} else if (izbranaBarva == "RAL9005") {
cenaVrata += 70;
}

if (izbranaKljucavnica == "cilinder") {
cenaVrata += 80;
} else if (izbranaKljucavnica == "elektronska") {
cenaVrata += 150;
}

if (izbranaResetka == "PVC") {
cenaVrata += 1;
} else if (izbranaResetka == "KOVINSKA") {
cenaVrata += 2;
}

var cenaElement = document.getElementById("cena");
cenaElement.innerHTML = "Cena vrat: " + cenaVrata + " €";

izracunajCeno();
generirajOpis();

}
```

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
resetiraj();
    });  
    
function shrani() {

var izbranaTip = document.getElementById("tip").value;
var izbranaSirina = document.getElementById("sirina").value;
var izbranaVisina = document.getElementById("visina").value;
var izbranaBarva = document.getElementById("barva").value;
var izbranaKljucavnica = document.getElementById("kljucavnica").value;
var izbranaResetka = document.getElementById("resetka").value;
var izbranaModel = document.getElementById("model").value;

var pozicijeElement = document.getElementById("pozicije");

var pozicije = pozicijeElement.getElementsByClassName("pozicija-item");
var najvisjaZaporednaStevilka = 0;
for (var i = 0; i \< pozicije.length; i++) {
var pozicijaElement = pozicije\[i\];
var pozicija = parseInt(pozicijaElement.getAttribute("data-pozicija"));
if (pozicija \> najvisjaZaporednaStevilka) {
najvisjaZaporednaStevilka = pozicija;
}
}

var naslednjaZaporednaStevilka = najvisjaZaporednaStevilka + 1;

var pozicijaElement = document.createElement("div");
pozicijaElement.innerHTML = "Pozicija " + naslednjaZaporednaStevilka + ": " + izbranaModel + ","     + izbranaTip + "," + izbranaSirina + "," + izbranaVisina + ", " + izbranaBarva + "," + izbranaKljucavnica + "," + izbranaResetka;

pozicijaElement.setAttribute("onclick", "popraviPozicijo(this)");
pozicijaElement.classList.add("pozicija-item");
pozicijaElement.setAttribute("data-pozicija", naslednjaZaporednaStevilka);

pozicijeElement.appendChild(pozicijaElement);
}

function popraviPozicijo(element) {
var pozicijaPodatki = element.innerHTML.split(": ")\[1\].trim();

var regex = /(\[^,\]+),\\s\*(\[^,\]+),\\s\*(\[^,\]+),\\s\*(\[^,\]+),\\s\*(\[^,\]+),\\s\*(\[^,\]+),\\s\*(\[^,\]+)/;
var ujemanje = regex.exec(pozicijaPodatki);

var izbranaModel = ujemanje\[1\];
var izbranaTip = ujemanje\[2\];
var izbranaSirina = ujemanje\[3\];
var izbranaVisina = ujemanje\[4\];
var izbranaBarva = ujemanje\[5\];
var izbranaKljucavnica = ujemanje\[6\];
var izbranaResetka = ujemanje\[7\];

document.getElementById("tip").value = izbranaTip;
document.getElementById("sirina").value = izbranaSirina;
document.getElementById("visina").value = izbranaVisina;
document.getElementById("barva").value = izbranaBarva;
document.getElementById("kljucavnica").value = izbranaKljucavnica;
document.getElementById("resetka").value = izbranaResetka;
document.getElementById("model").value = izbranaModel;

var pozicije = document.getElementsByClassName("pozicija-item");
for (var i = 0; i \< pozicije.length; i++) {
pozicije\[i\].classList.remove("oznaceno");
}

element.classList.add("oznaceno");
prikaziOpis(izbranaModel, izbranaTip, izbranaSirina, izbranaVisina, izbranaBarva, izbranaKljucavnica, izbranaResetka);
izracunajCeno();
}

function prikaziOpis(model, tip, sirina, visina, barva, kljucavnica, resetka) {
var opisElement = document.getElementById("opis");
var opis = "- " + model + "  
";  
opis += "- " + tip + "  
";
opis += "- DIMENZIJA: " + sirina + " mm x " + visina + " mm  
";
opis += "- " + barva + "  
";
opis += "- " + kljucavnica + "  
";
opis += "- " + resetka + "  
";

opisElement.innerHTML = opis;
}

function izracunajCeno() {
var izbranaTip = document.getElementById("tip").value;
var izbranaModel = document.getElementById("model").value;

if (izbranaTip === "ENOKRILNA" && izbranaModel == "PROGET EI60") {
izracunajCenoPRENO();  
}

else if (izbranaTip === "DVOKRILNA" && izbranaModel == "PROGET EI60") {
izracunajCenoPRDVO();
}

else if (izbranaTip === "ENOKRILNA" && izbranaModel == "PROGET MULTI") {
izracunajCenoPRMENO();
}

}

function preveriObsegDimenzij(izbranaDimenzija, obsegDimenzij) {
var dimenzije = obsegDimenzij.split('-');
var minDimenzija = dimenzije\[0\];
var maxDimenzija = dimenzije\[1\] || dimenzije\[0\]; // Uporablja enako dimenzijo, če ni določena največja dimenzija

var izbraneSirina = parseInt(izbranaDimenzija.split('x')\[0\]);
var izbraneVisina = parseInt(izbranaDimenzija.split('x')\[1\]);

var minSirina = parseInt(minDimenzija.split('x')\[0\]);
var minVisina = parseInt(minDimenzija.split('x')\[1\]);

var maxSirina = parseInt(maxDimenzija.split('x')\[0\]);
var maxVisina = parseInt(maxDimenzija.split('x')\[1\]);

return (
izbraneSirina \>= minSirina && izbraneSirina \<= maxSirina &&
izbraneVisina \>= minVisina && izbraneVisina \<= maxVisina
);
}

function izracunajCenoPRENO() {
var izbranaTip = document.getElementById("tip").value;
var izbranaSirina = document.getElementById("sirina").value;
var izbranaVisina = document.getElementById("visina").value;
var izbranaBarva = document.getElementById("barva").value;
var izbranaKljucavnica = document.getElementById("kljucavnica").value;
var izbranaResetka = document.getElementById("resetka").value;

var cenaVrata = 0;

var ceneVrat = {
"800x2000": 430,
"900x2000": 451,
"1000x2000": 464,
"1300x2000": 603,

"800x2050": 430,
"900x2050": 451,
"1000x2050": 464,
"1100x2050": 549,
"1200x2050": 579,
"1300x2050": 603,
"1340x2050": 613,

"800x2100": 477,
"900x2100": 494,
"1000x2100": 519,
"1100x2100": 568,
"1200x2100": 603,
"1300x2100": 622,
"1340x2100": 637,

"800x2150": 445,
"900x2150": 464,
"1000x2150": 485,
"1100x2150": 568,
"1200x2150": 603,
"1300x2150": 622,
"1340x2150": 637,

"800x2200": 489,
"900x2200": 519,
"1000x2200": 539,
"1100x2200": 630,
"1200x2200": 665,
"1300x2200": 688,
"1340x2200": 694,

"670x1950-800x2050": 523,
"801x1950-900x2050": 539,
"901x1950-1000x2050": 560,
"1001x1950-1100x2050": 601,
"1101x1950-1200x2050": 626,
"1201x1950-1340x2050": 658,

"670x2051-800x2150": 528,
"801x2051-900x2150": 545,
"901x2051-1000x2150": 566,
"1001x2051-1100x2150": 613,
"1101x2051-1200x2150": 635,
"1201x2051-1340x2150": 665,

"670x2151-900x2300": 581,
"901x2151-1125x2300": 632,
"1126x2151-1340x2300": 694,

"670x2301-900x2500": 607,
"901x2301-1125x2500": 658,
"1126x2301-1340x2500": 722,

"670x2501-900x2600": 632,
"901x2501-1125x2600": 722,
"1126x2501-1340x2600": 804,

};

var izbranaDimenzija = izbranaSirina + "x" + izbranaVisina;
var dimenzije = Object.keys(ceneVrat);

for (var i = 0; i \< dimenzije.length; i++) {
var dimenzija = dimenzije\[i\];

if (dimenzija.includes("-")) {
var razpon = dimenzija.split("-");
var minDimenzije = razpon\[0\].split("x");
var maxDimenzije = razpon\[1\].split("x");
var minSirina = parseInt(minDimenzije\[0\]);
var maxSirina = parseInt(maxDimenzije\[0\]);
var minVisina = parseInt(minDimenzije\[1\]);
var maxVisina = parseInt(maxDimenzije\[1\]);

    if (
      izbranaSirina >= minSirina &&
      izbranaSirina <= maxSirina &&
      izbranaVisina >= minVisina &&
      izbranaVisina <= maxVisina
    ) {
      cenaVrata += ceneVrat[dimenzija];
      break;
    }

} else if (dimenzija === izbranaDimenzija) {
cenaVrata += ceneVrat\[dimenzija\];
break;
}
}

if (izbranaBarva == "RAL8014") {
cenaVrata +=  50 + izbranaSirina \* izbranaVisina / 1000000;
} else if (izbranaBarva == "RAL9005") {
cenaVrata += 70;
}

if (izbranaKljucavnica == "cilinder") {
cenaVrata += 80;
} else if (izbranaKljucavnica == "elektronska") {
cenaVrata += 150;
}

if (izbranaResetka == "PVC") {
cenaVrata += 1;
} else if (izbranaResetka == "KOVINSKA") {
cenaVrata += 2;
}

var cenaElement = document.getElementById("cena");
cenaElement.innerHTML = "Cena vrat: " + cenaVrata + " €";

izracunajCeno();
generirajOpis();

}

function izracunajCenoPRDVO() {

var izbranaTip = document.getElementById("tip").value;
var izbranaSirina = document.getElementById("sirina").value;
var izbranaVisina = document.getElementById("visina").value;
var izbranaBarva = document.getElementById("barva").value;
var izbranaKljucavnica = document.getElementById("kljucavnica").value;
var izbranaResetka = document.getElementById("resetka").value;

var cenaVrata = 0;

var ceneVrat = {
"1150x2000": 868,
"1200x2000": 883,
"1250x2000": 888,
"1300x2000": 896,
"1350x2000": 907,
"1400x2000": 923,
"1450x2000": 932,
"1600x2000": 960,
"1700x2000": 980,
"1800x2000": 997,
"1900x2000": 1021,
"2000x2000": 1041,

"1150x2100": 942,
"1200x2100": 955,
"1250x2100": 971,
"1300x2100": 982,
"1350x2100": 990,
"1400x2100": 1001,
"1450x2100": 1006,
"1600x2100": 1045,
"1700x2100": 1071,
"1800x2100": 1089,
"1900x2100": 1106,
"2000x2100": 1131,

"1150x2150": 894,
"1200x2150": 907,
"1250x2150": 925,
"1300x2150": 934,
"1350x2150": 942,
"1400x2150": 949,
"1450x2150": 958,
"1600x2150": 993,
"1700x2150": 1017,
"1800x2150": 1037,
"1900x2150": 1056,
"2000x2150": 1078,

"1150x2200": 984,
"1200x2200": 999,
"1250x2200": 1017,
"1300x2200": 1028,
"1350x2200": 1037,
"1400x2200": 1049,
"1450x2200": 1054,
"1600x2200": 1091,
"1700x2200": 1117,
"1800x2200": 1141,
"1900x2200": 1163,
"2000x2200": 1183,

"890x1775-1260x2050": 1002,
"1261x1775-1280x2050": 1021,
"1281x1775-1380x2050": 1037,
"1381x1775-1430x2050": 1047,
"1431x1775-1480x2050": 1065,
"1481x1775-1530x2050": 1065,
"1531x1775-1600x2050": 1065,
"1601x1775-1800x2050": 1096,
"1801x1775-2000x2050": 1135,
"2001x1775-2200x2050": 1225,
"2201x1775-2400x2050": 1259,
"2401x1775-2540x2050": 1295,

"890x2051-1260x2150": 1023,
"1261x2051-1280x2150": 1036,
"1281x2051-1380x2150": 1054,
"1381x2051-1430x2150": 1058,
"1431x2051-1480x2150": 1084,
"1481x2051-1530x2150": 1080,
"1531x2051-1600x2150": 1085,
"1601x2051-1800x2150": 1133,
"1801x2051-2000x2150": 1170,
"2001x2051-2200x2150": 1286,
"2201x2051-2400x2150": 1329,
"2401x2051-2540x2150": 1329,

"890x2151-1100x2300": 1029,
"1101x2151-1340x2300": 1080,
"1341x2151-1800x2300": 1176,
"1801x2151-2250x2300": 1295,
"2251x2151-2540x2300": 1412,

"890x2301-1100x2500": 1050,
"1101x2301-1340x2500": 1109,
"1341x2301-1800x2500": 1216,
"1801x2301-2250x2500": 1334,
"2251x2301-2540x2500": 1465,

"890x2501-1100x2600": 1141,
"1101x2501-1340x2600": 1209,
"1341x2501-1800x2600": 1286,
"1801x2501-2250x2600": 1467,
"2251x2501-2540x2600": 1622,

};

var izbranaDimenzija = izbranaSirina + "x" + izbranaVisina;
var dimenzije = Object.keys(ceneVrat);

for (var i = 0; i \< dimenzije.length; i++) {
var dimenzija = dimenzije\[i\];

if (dimenzija.includes("-")) {
var razpon = dimenzija.split("-");
var minDimenzije = razpon\[0\].split("x");
var maxDimenzije = razpon\[1\].split("x");
var minSirina = parseInt(minDimenzije\[0\]);
var maxSirina = parseInt(maxDimenzije\[0\]);
var minVisina = parseInt(minDimenzije\[1\]);
var maxVisina = parseInt(maxDimenzije\[1\]);

    if (
      izbranaSirina >= minSirina &&
      izbranaSirina <= maxSirina &&
      izbranaVisina >= minVisina &&
      izbranaVisina <= maxVisina
    ) {
      cenaVrata += ceneVrat[dimenzija];
      break;
    }

} else if (dimenzija === izbranaDimenzija) {
cenaVrata += ceneVrat\[dimenzija\];
break;
}
}

if (izbranaBarva == "RAL8014") {
cenaVrata += 50;
} else if (izbranaBarva == "RAL9005") {
cenaVrata += 70;
}

if (izbranaKljucavnica == "cilinder") {
cenaVrata += 80;
} else if (izbranaKljucavnica == "elektronska") {
cenaVrata += 150;
}

if (izbranaResetka == "PVC") {
cenaVrata += 1;
} else if (izbranaResetka == "KOVINSKA") {
cenaVrata += 2;
}

var cenaElement = document.getElementById("cena");
cenaElement.innerHTML = "Cena vrat: " + cenaVrata + " €";

izracunajCeno();
generirajOpis();

}

function izracunajCenoPRMENO() {
var izbranaTip = document.getElementById("tip").value;
var izbranaSirina = document.getElementById("sirina").value;
var izbranaVisina = document.getElementById("visina").value;
var izbranaBarva = document.getElementById("barva").value;
var izbranaKljucavnica = document.getElementById("kljucavnica").value;
var izbranaResetka = document.getElementById("resetka").value;

var cenaVrata = 0;

var ceneVrat = {
"800x2000": 397,
"900x2000": 408,
"1000x2000": 426,
"1300x2000": 510,

"800x2050": 399,
"900x2050": 411,
"1000x2050": 429,
"1100x2050": 474,
"1200x2050": 496,
"1300x2050": 512,
"1340x2050": 525,

"800x2100": 438,
"900x2100": 449,
"1000x2100": 467,
"1100x2100": 489,
"1200x2100": 503,
"1300x2100": 523,
"1340x2100": 541,

"800x2150": 406,
"900x2150": 419,
"1000x2150": 437,
"1100x2150": 487,
"1200x2150": 501,
"1300x2150": 521,
"1340x2150": 539,

"800x2200": 451,
"900x2200": 460,
"1000x2200": 482,
"1100x2200": 528,
"1200x2200": 546,
"1300x2200": 566,
"1340x2200": 571,

"500x1750-640x2050": 433,
"641x1750-800x2050": 465,
"801x1750-900x2050": 478,
"901x1750-1000x2050": 498,
"1001x1750-1100x2050": 510,
"1101x1750-1240x2050": 528,
"1201x1750-1340x2050": 553,

"500x2051-640x2150": 592,
"641x2051-800x2150": 473,
"801x2051-900x2150": 496,
"901x2051-1000x2150": 505,
"1001x2051-1100x2150": 541,
"1101x2051-1240x2150": 559,
"1201x2051-1340x2150": 577,

"500x2151-900x2300": 519,
"901x2151-1125x2300": 575,
"1126x2151-1340x2300": 611,

"500x2301-900x2500": 632,
"901x2301-1125x2500": 589,
"1126x2301-1340x2500": 640,

"500x2501-900x2600": 562,
"901x2501-1125x2600": 625,
"1126x2501-1340x2600": 702,

};

var izbranaDimenzija = izbranaSirina + "x" + izbranaVisina;
var dimenzije = Object.keys(ceneVrat);

for (var i = 0; i \< dimenzije.length; i++) {
var dimenzija = dimenzije\[i\];

if (dimenzija.includes("-")) {
var razpon = dimenzija.split("-");
var minDimenzije = razpon\[0\].split("x");
var maxDimenzije = razpon\[1\].split("x");
var minSirina = parseInt(minDimenzije\[0\]);
var maxSirina = parseInt(maxDimenzije\[0\]);
var minVisina = parseInt(minDimenzije\[1\]);
var maxVisina = parseInt(maxDimenzije\[1\]);

    if (
      izbranaSirina >= minSirina &&
      izbranaSirina <= maxSirina &&
      izbranaVisina >= minVisina &&
      izbranaVisina <= maxVisina
    ) {
      cenaVrata += ceneVrat[dimenzija];
      break;
    }

} else if (dimenzija === izbranaDimenzija) {
cenaVrata += ceneVrat\[dimenzija\];
break;
}
}

if (izbranaBarva == "RAL8014") {
cenaVrata +=  50 + izbranaSirina \* izbranaVisina / 1000000;
} else if (izbranaBarva == "RAL9005") {
cenaVrata += 70;
}

if (izbranaKljucavnica == "cilinder") {
cenaVrata += 80;
} else if (izbranaKljucavnica == "elektronska") {
cenaVrata += 150;
}

if (izbranaResetka == "PVC") {
cenaVrata += 1;
} else if (izbranaResetka == "KOVINSKA") {
cenaVrata += 2;
}

var cenaElement = document.getElementById("cena");
cenaElement.innerHTML = "Cena vrat: " + cenaVrata + " €";

izracunajCeno();
generirajOpis();

}

function generirajOpis() {
var izbranaModel = document.getElementById("model").value;
var izbranaTip = document.getElementById("tip").value;
var izbranaSirina = document.getElementById("sirina").value;
var izbranaVisina = document.getElementById("visina").value;
var izbranaBarva = document.getElementById("barva").value;
var izbranaKljucavnica = document.getElementById("kljucavnica").value;
var izbranaResetka = document.getElementById("resetka").value;

prikaziOpis(izbranaModel, izbranaTip, izbranaSirina, izbranaVisina, izbranaBarva, izbranaKljucavnica, izbranaResetka);

var izbraniElementi = document.querySelectorAll("#model, #tip, #sirina, #visina, #barva, #kljucavnica, #resetka");
izbraniElementi.forEach(function (element) {
element.addEventListener("input", function () {
izracunajCeno();
generirajOpis();
});
});
}

var shraniBtn = document.getElementById("shrani");
shraniBtn.addEventListener("click", shrani);

var resetirajBtn = document.getElementById("resetiraj");
resetirajBtn.addEventListener("click", resetiraj);

izracunajCeno();
generirajOpis();

function resetiraj() {
document.getElementById("model").value = "";
document.getElementById("tip").value = "";
document.getElementById("sirina").value = "";
document.getElementById("visina").value = "";
document.getElementById("barva").value = "";
document.getElementById("kljucavnica").value = "";
document.getElementById("resetka").value = "";

var pozicijeElement = document.getElementById("pozicije");
pozicijeElement.innerHTML = "";

pozicija = 1;

var opisElement = document.getElementById("opis");
opisElement.innerHTML = "";

var cenaElement = document.getElementById("cena");
cenaElement.innerHTML = "Cena: 0 €";

var modelElement = document.getElementById("model");
var tipElement = document.getElementById("tip");
var sirinaElement = document.getElementById("sirina");
var visinaElement = document.getElementById("visina");
var barvaElement = document.getElementById("barva");
var kljucavnicaElement = document.getElementById("kljucavnica");
var resetkaElement = document.getElementById("resetka");

modelElement.addEventListener("input", function() {
izracunajCeno();
});

tipElement.addEventListener("input", function() {
izracunajCeno();
});

sirinaElement.addEventListener("input", function() {
izracunajCeno();
});

visinaElement.addEventListener("input", function() {
izracunajCeno();
});

barvaElement.addEventListener("input", function() {
izracunajCeno();
});

kljucavnicaElement.addEventListener("input", function() {
izracunajCeno();
});

resetkaElement.addEventListener("input", function() {
izracunajCeno();
});

}

var shraniBtn = document.getElementById("shrani");
shraniBtn.addEventListener("click", shrani);

var resetirajBtn = document.getElementById("resetiraj");
resetirajBtn.addEventListener("click", resetiraj);

izracunajCeno();
generirajOpis();

function posodobiPozicijo() {
var izbranaTip = document.getElementById("tip").value;
var izbranaSirina = document.getElementById("sirina").value;
var izbranaVisina = document.getElementById("visina").value;
var izbranaBarva = document.getElementById("barva").value;
var izbranaKljucavnica = document.getElementById("kljucavnica").value;
var izbranaResetka = document.getElementById("resetka").value;
var izbranaModel = document.getElementById("model").value;

var pozicijaElementi = document.getElementsByClassName("pozicija-item");

var pozicijaElement;
if (pozicijaElementi.length \> 0) {
var rdecaPozicija = document.querySelector(".oznaceno");
if (rdecaPozicija) {
rdecaPozicija.innerHTML = "Pozicija " + (Array.from(rdecaPozicija.parentNode.children).indexOf(rdecaPozicija) + 1) + ": " + izbranaModel + "," + izbranaTip + "," + izbranaSirina + "," + izbranaVisina + ","+ izbranaBarva + "," + izbranaKljucavnica + "," + izbranaResetka;
rdecaPozicija.classList.remove("oznaceno");
}
} else {
pozicijaElement = document.createElement("div");
pozicijaElement.innerHTML = "Pozicija " + (pozicijaElementi.length + 1) + ": " + izbranaModel + "," + izbranaTip + "," + izbranaSirina + "," + izbranaVisina + ","+ izbranaBarva + "," + izbranaKljucavnica + "," + izbranaResetka;
pozicijaElement.classList.add("pozicija-item");
pozicijaElement.classList.add("oznaceno");

    var pozicijeElement = document.getElementById("pozicije");
    pozicijeElement.appendChild(pozicijaElement);

}
}

function izbrisi() {
var rdecaPozicija = document.querySelector(".oznaceno");
if (rdecaPozicija) {
var pozicijeElement = document.getElementById("pozicije");
pozicijeElement.removeChild(rdecaPozicija);

    var pozicijaElementi = document.getElementsByClassName("pozicija-item");
    for (var i = 0; i < pozicijaElementi.length; i++) {
      var pozicijaElement = pozicijaElementi[i];
      pozicijaElement.innerHTML = "Pozicija " + (i + 1) + ": " + pozicijaElement.innerHTML.split(":")[1];
      pozicijaElement.setAttribute("data-pozicija", i + 1);
    }

}
}

function preveriBarvo() {
var izbranaBarva = document.getElementById("barva").value;
var kljucavnicaElement = document.getElementById("kljucavnica");
var elektronskaOption = kljucavnicaElement.querySelector('option\[value="elektronska"\]');

if (izbranaBarva === "RAL9010") {
kljucavnicaElement.value = "";  // Clear the selected option
kljucavnicaElement.disabled = false;
elektronskaOption.disabled = true;

} else {
kljucavnicaElement.disabled = false;
elektronskaOption.disabled = false;
}
}

}

if (izbranaBarva == "RAL8014") {
cenaVrata +=  50 + izbranaSirina \* izbranaVisina / 1000000;
} else if (izbranaBarva == "RAL9005") {
cenaVrata += 70;
}

if (izbranaKljucavnica == "cilinder") {
cenaVrata += 80;
} else if (izbranaKljucavnica == "elektronska") {
cenaVrata += 150;
}

if (izbranaResetka == "PVC") {
cenaVrata += 1;
} else if (izbranaResetka == "KOVINSKA") {
cenaVrata += 2;
}

var cenaElement = document.getElementById("cena");
cenaElement.innerHTML = "Cena vrat: " + cenaVrata + " €";

izracunajCeno();
generirajOpis();

}
```

I am trying to make it simplier....

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) first.

Comment: Also, when you posted your code, it got mangled by the addition of backslashes. Make sure that doesn't happen when you re-post.